# Powershell script to list ,in reverse order, files recursively, similarly to this bash script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert this bash script to powershell. I'm doing this because Windows subsystem for Linux currently doesn't work on Google Drive File System's mounted drives so I need to use powershell.

## Background

I need to run this powershell script on a top-level parent folder to import 87 million json files in ~700,000 deeply nested folders. I'm open to better ways of doing this.

## My Bash Solution

```
#!/bin/sh

function import_from_start() {
    echo "starting import from front"
    find "$1" -name '*.json' | while read file; do
        mongoimport --host=datalake7 --db=CA_facebook_copy --collection=test_import --type="json" --file="$file"
    done
}

function import_from_end() {
    echo "starting import from back end"
    find "$1" -name '*.json' | sort -r | cut -f2 | while read file; do
        mongoimport --host=datalake7 --db=CA_facebook_copy --collection=test_import --type="json" --file="$file"
    done
}

import_from_start "$1" &
import_from_end "$1"
```

## My current attempted powershell script

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Src,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Collection
 )

$Extension = '*.json'
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Filter $Extension -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {

    .\mongoimport.exe --host datalake7 --db CA_facebook_copy --collection $Collection --type json --file $_.FullName
}
```

## My Goal

I need to import from the start and from the end of the file list at the same time. I'm using this approach because its very slow to create and destroy a connection to mongodb for each file.

Comment: What is not working? Or does it work and you just need to sort backwards? Or is it just to slow?

Comment: I need to import from the start and from the end of the file list at the same time. I'm using this approach because its very slow to create and destroy a connection to mongodb for each file.

Comment: How does your Bash approach not create a new MongoDB connection every time, given that you're calling `mongoimport` for each filename? What is the point of `cut -f2`, given that `cut`'s default separator is `\t`? How do you prevent processing the same file twice, given that the two commands ultimately process _all_ files?

Comment: You are right, it does. But for some reason unknown to me, its a lot slower in powershell than bash. To answer your second question, I use have a unique key on json `id`, so duplicates are skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now sorting could be based on any column. So in your case, you can take the all files **fullname.length** since you have used fullname and can sort that in descending order.

**Replace**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Filter $Extension -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {

    .\mongoimport.exe --host datalake7 --db CA_facebook_copy --collection $Collection --type json --file $_.FullName
}
```

**With this:**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Filter $Extension -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {

    .\mongoimport.exe --host datalake7 --db CA_facebook_copy --collection $Collection --type json --file $_.FullName
}| Sort-Object @{expression = {$_.fullname.length}} -descending
```

I have added the sort object part after the foreach loop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `| Sort-Object @{expression = {$_.fullname.length}} -descending` was what I needed. Thanks!